# How to use JSON sent with 400 error from Flask with fetch in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch

Using fetch, how do I show an alert with the "message" from the JSON sent from Flask when a (400) error is detected?

When an error is NOT detected (200 code is received) it should show an alert with "successfully registered" then follow Flask redirect.

**Flask code:**

```
 @app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def register():
        """Register user"""
    
        if request.method == "GET":
            return render_template("register.html")
        else:
            registerForm = request.get_json(force=True)
            username = registerForm.get("username")
            password = registerForm.get("password")
            confirmPassword = registerForm.get("confirmPassword")
            username_matches = getUserMatches(username)

            if password != confirmPassword:
                return(jsonify({"message" : "Passwords do not match!"}),400)
            elif len(username_matches) != 0):
                return(jsonify({"message" : "Username is taken!"}),400)
            else:
                return redirect("/login",code=200)
```

**JS code:**

```
function registerUser(event) {

    userRegistrationInput = {
        "username" : registerForm["username"].value,
        "password" : registerForm["password"].value,
        "confirmPassword" : registerForm["confirm-password"].value
    }

    fetch('/register',
    {
        body: JSON.stringify(userRegistrationInput),
        credentials: 'include',
        method: "POST",
        redirect: 'follow'
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(responseJSON) {
       //When Flask returns 200, show alert saying "successfully registered" then follow Flask redirect
    })
    .catch(function(responseJSON) {
        //When Flask returns 400, show alert() containing the message in the JSON
    });

    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `response.status` to first check the status of the response and then do operation on it as per your use case.